# Adding a property to a class from a different assembly

Tags: c#, mongodb, oop, n-tier-architecture, onion-architecture

I have `.NET` solution that follows the `Onion Architecture`.

According to the guidlines of this type of architecture, the `Core` layer, where my entities are, must be abstract and not reference any external library.

I also want to connect to a `MongoDb` database which requires that the `Id` attribute of an entity should be of type `ObjectId`, which is a Mongo type.

```
namespace MyApp.Core.Entities.Base
{
  using System;
  **using MongoDB.Bson;** // This is an external library that should not be referenced by Core

  public class BaseEntity
  {
     public **ObjectId** Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
  }
}
```

So if I add this attribute type to entity in the Core layer, that would mean that I will have to reference MongoDb inside my Core layer, and that would be a violation of the Onion Architecture guidelines. My solution, I guess, would be to make some kind of partial class outside of the Core layer (which is not possible) inside of which I will add my ObjectId property.

Any idea of how I could accomplish that ?

Comment: "I also want to connect to a MongoDb database which requires that the Id attribute of an entity should be of type ObjectId, which is a Mongo type." Then either the Database adapter class is not a core element. Or you will not get around ignoring the rule for that one time. Personally I would prefer the former. Make it a habit to make dedicated Database Interace classes. Make them a single instance that you hand around. That way switching to anotehr backend DBMS is easy.

Comment: The database adapater is not a Core element, it is in fact in the Infrastructure layer. But it will use the entities from the Core layer.

Answer (score 0):

"According to the guidlines of this type of architecture, the Core layer, where my entities are, must be abstract and not reference any external library.

I also want to connect to a MongoDb database which requires that the Id attribute of an entity should be of type ObjectId, which is a Mongo type."

That leaves you two options:

1. Ignore the rule in that case. Maybe you could do soemthing with Generics.
2. Make a Database adapter class wich is not part of the core Libraries.

Option 2 is something I would always advise. Always make a "DatabaseAdapater" class. Use one instance across the entire Project. If you ever need to support a different DMBS, it is as simple as: Extract Interface/Abstract class -> Write a new variant -> change out the instantiation at one point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `Id` of your base entity as `object` type.

```
public class BaseEntity
  {
     public object Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
  }
```

With this, you can have any type of Id in DB and your DB Adapter should be able to convert the `BaseEntity Id` to the target type.

This will not only help you retain your architecture intact with MongoDb, but any DB/ID Column Type you may use in future.

Hope this helps!